# Can you save Instances in the Table?

Tags: lua, roblox

When i try to save instance with same name in the table, it overrides it instead of creating second key. Can't we save it as reference?

example that im trying to do:

```
local t = {}


local model1 = Instance.new("Model")
local model2 = Instance.new("Model")

t[model1] = model1
t[model2] = model2
```

Comment: If you use `table.insert(t, Instance.new("Model"))` it will insert the instance into the table with a numbered index instead of a key. Since it just inserts new indexes, there will never be an override.

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing as not "save it as a reference", I suspect `Instance.new("Model")` will just return the same object if the name already exists. so your `model1` and `model2` are equal you could even verify this by doing `print (model1 == model2)`. this means the issue has nothing to do with the table but that your just creating the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you can use the Models as keys or as values and it works just fine.

```
local model1 = Instance.new("Model")
local model2 = Instance.new("Model")
print(model1 == model2) -- false

local t = {}

-- use the models as keys
t[model1] = "a"
t[model2] = "b"
print(t[model1], t[model2], t[model1] == t[model2]) -- a, b, false

-- use the models as values
t["a"] = model1
t["b"] = model2
print(t["a"], t["b"], t["a"] == t["b"]) -- Model, Model, false

-- use the models as keys and values
t[model1] = model1
t[model2] = model2
print(t[model1], t[model2], t[model1] == t[model2]) -- Model, Model, false

-- show all the keys stored in the table
t = {}
t[model1] = model1
t[model2] = model2
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    print(k, v)
end
--[[ prints out :
    Model Model (x2)
]]
```

The last example shows that there is no collision in the key indexing and both models are stored properly. It may just be a little difficult to see the difference because both Models have the same name.

That being said, it doesn't make much sense to store the model as *both* the key and value, because if you can access the key, you've already got the Model.

TL;DR: Your code works just fine.